# Prevent clang from expanding arguments that are aggregate types?

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm

I'm using clang to spit out optimized LLVM IR for some C code and I've hit a snag. I'd assumed that, if I only passed functions to clang one at a time (with the necessary dependencies declared), the function signatures of the resulting LLVM routines would be consistent with the functions I'd passed in (ie. same number of arguments with the same types). This works for the most part, except in the case of aggregate types. For example:

The following C code

```
struct A {
    double x;
    int y;
};

int f(struct A a) {
    return a.y;
}
```

Results in the following LLVM

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind readnone uwtable
define i32 @f(double %a.coerce0, i32 %a.coerce1) #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 %a.coerce1
}
```

The struct has been expanded into consecutive arguments so that the function now appears to accept two arguments instead of one. Is there any way of preventing this type  of expansion? Even if it's some way of forward declaring the struct so that clang won't know about its constituent fields in order to expand it?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is specified by the [AMD64 ABI](http://people.freebsd.org/~obrien/amd64-elf-abi.pdf) (application binary interface for x86 64-bit architecture). It's specified in the ABI so that functions compiled by different compilers can interoperate. For the same reason, it cannot be changed without violating the ABI, which would mean that *all* clients of the function would need to know how it was to be called.

The ABI requires that aggregate objects be split in this fashion if:

- The aggregate object is not more than 16 bytes in size, and
- In the case of C++, the aggregate object is "POD" (Plain Old Data).

Otherwise, the argument is passed by address (although a copy still needs to be made).

So you can defeat the deaggregation of aggregate types by making the type larger, but that must be visible to every translation unit which uses the type.

Comment: That's fascinating! Thanks for the answer. Is the spec similar for most 32 bit architectures as well? Or could I potentially switch over to x86 to avoid the problem entirely?

Comment: @Hoyt: The 32-bit ABI is based on an architecture with considerably fewer registers, so it doesn't work so hard at optimizing calls. IIRC, in 32-bit mode aggregates are never deaggregated, although small ones might be passed in a single register. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions for more info. Note: don't be confused by the use of `AMD`; the same ABI is used for Intel x86 in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @Hoyt: Deliberately using 32-bit mode seems to be a contradiction to the desire to emit *optimized* code, as in the OP. Just sayin'.

Comment: Yeah, I'll be the first to admit that I've had to strip away a lot of the optimization potential in the name of time to market (e.g. removing any possibility of global optimizations by splitting into functional compilation units). Compiling for 32-bit arch isn't the end of the world, although I'd love to avoid it if possible and this is a pretty clever trick by x86_64...

Comment: @hoyt: Your other option is to force pass-by-reference (i.e. pass a pointer) and copy the struct in the callee's prelude.I dont know enough about your project to suggest anything else.Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass things around by void * and cast the memory to the struct you want, but a better question is why you're trying to avoid having the front end do some of the type based lowering it's required to do (The ABI answer above). FWIW we could do this in the back end as well, but it requires front end type information to do the lowering correctly and is a bit of a large change for llvm and clang.