# Why does the same C structure type get translated into two different LLVM IR types when compiling with clang

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++

I am writing an LLVM pass which has to deal with structure fields and I came across this behaviour which I cannot explain to myself.

I have the following C++ file:

```
struct vec3 {
  unsigned x, y, z;
};


vec3 foo();
vec3 *foo2();

void bar(vec3 d);
void bar2(vec3 *d);


void user() {
  foo();
  foo2();
  vec3 tmp;
  bar(tmp);
  bar2(&tmp);
}
```

When compiled to LLVM IR using `clang++ -cc1 -emit-llvm vec3test.cpp -O3`, we get this output (I am pasting only the relevant bits):

```
%struct.vec3 = type { i32, i32, i32 }

; Function Attrs: mustprogress nounwind
define dso_local void @_Z4userv() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %tmp = alloca %struct.vec3, align 8
  %call = tail call { i64, i32 } @_Z3foov() #3
  %call1 = tail call %struct.vec3* @_Z4foo2v() #3
  %0 = bitcast %struct.vec3* %tmp to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start.p0i8(i64 12, i8* nonnull %0) #3
  tail call void @_Z3bar4vec3(i64 undef, i32 undef) #3
  call void @_Z4bar2P4vec3(%struct.vec3* nonnull %tmp) #3
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end.p0i8(i64 12, i8* nonnull %0) #3
  ret void
}

declare { i64, i32 } @_Z3foov() local_unnamed_addr #1

declare %struct.vec3* @_Z4foo2v() local_unnamed_addr #1

declare void @_Z3bar4vec3(i64, i32) local_unnamed_addr #1

declare void @_Z4bar2P4vec3(%struct.vec3*) local_unnamed_addr #1
```

So it seems that when a pointer is being passed around (as an argument or return value), it has a type `{ i64, i32 }`. It looks like the `x` and `y` fields were combined in one `i64`.

However, when a pointer is involved, the type becomes `{ i32, i32, i32 }`, which is to be expected.

I thought this might be because of some optimisation, however even when compiled using `-O0` the result is the same.

Why does this happen? This makes it necessary to do type conversions when you mix functions that use pointers and ones that use values so it does not seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: I think this is an optimization. Since passing/returning by value potentially involves copies, then using i64 instead of two i32 is potentially faster. Also type conversions is not an issue, in this case it is for free anyway. Remember that the compiler's job is to produce a code that is efficient, not nice for a human to read. Finally I don't think `-O0` means "no optimizations". That would be even hard to define. I think it should be understood as "base optimizations".

Comment: Alongside there being a basis in optimisation behind this translation, it's also really part of Clang's effort at ABI compatibility: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386912/prevent-clang-from-expanding-arguments-that-are-aggregate-types